# Resharper completion won't look for different namespaces in project since v9

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-9.0

I may have done something wrong because since the v9 I can't get resharper to suggest classes from different namespaces (different from the current one) if I don't type the using first.

But anything outside the project is ok. So it looks in imported dlls without any problem but won't look in the current project.

Any idea how I could have done that? (looked at the jetbrains forum and didn't see any similar issue so I assume it's not a bug)

Thank you

Comment: have you tried clearing your Resharper cache? `Resharper->Options->Environment->General->Caches`)

Comment: @wal just tried it, still the same